# Can I install the Ubuntu SDK along side with PyQt?

Tags: pyqt, qt-creator, ubuntu-13.10

I installed the Ubuntu SDK and everything goes very well. Now I want to install PyQt just to mess around with it. PyQt comes with Qt Creator, but it was already installed by the Ubuntu SDK. How can I install PyQt in this conditions?

Answer (score 0):

```
1) QtCreator is a Qt/C++ developing IDE, so you may already have Qt intalled.
2) Downloads the corresponding's Pyqt, for example, if you have already 4.8.10 Qt installed, then try to download the PyQt 4.8.4.
3) Follow the readme instructor to have it installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use apt-get you could just use the command:

`sudo apt-get install python-qt4`

To test that this worked, open the python console and enter:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

If this does not give any errors, it worked!

Comment: It worked. It seems that I had python-qt4 already installed. But I want to install PyQt5, 'cause Ubuntu SDK works with Qt5. I'm installing it but I get the error _sip.h: No file or directory found_